# Android MediaPlayer video stream playback error on some devices

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an application reading streams of webcams. The application is currently in Alpha stage and some testers reported that they could not access some webcams.

The application requires at least Android 4.x and all streams are using http (so I could rule out most of issues I found concerning Froyo support and HTTPS support).

On some devices (Galaxy Note II, Galaxy S2, Galaxy Tab 8.9, Galaxy S3, Galaxy S4, LG Nexus 4, Asus Transformer, ) all is fine.
On some other devices (XPeria E, HTC One M7) we are not able to play some of the webcams, and we've got in the stacktrace:

```
E/ACodec(163): componentName = OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
E/ACodec(163): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -1010
E/NuPlayer(163): Received error from video decoder, aborting playback.
E/NuPlayer(163): video track encountered an error (-2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(14769): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(14769): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Stream URL is: 
`http://87.98.179.254:80/64connections/biarritzgrandeplage.stream/playlist.m3u8`

Any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each hardware manufacturer can supply their own set of decoders, looks like some handsets don't decode your avc stream correctly...

Comment: I knew that :) Any kind of helpful resource that could help resolve the problem?

Comment: Could fallback to software decoding using ffmpeg